# Error in `vec_as_location()` when trying to subset variables

Tags: r, vector, subset

I'm trying to subset some variables from my dataset, but I encounter an error.

```r
library(readxl)

Vitamin_D_MRS <- read_excel("~/Documents/OneDrive - Imperial College London/6. Micronutrients project/R_Directory_Demographics/Vitamin D MRS.xlsx", 
                                sheet = "MRS")
    
data <- subset(Vitamin_D_MRS, select = c(PCR_status, Sex, Age,
               BMI, ethnic, comorb, Vitamin_supplementation, Season, Exposure))
```

```
#Error message:
    Error in `vec_as_location()`:
    ! `...` must be empty.
    ✖ Problematic argument:
    • call = call
```

Comment: try `library(dplyr) data = Vitamin_D_MRS %>% select(PCR_status, Sex, Age,
               BMI, ethnic, comorb, Vitamin_supplementation, Season, Exposure)`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with a dataframe that contains those variables, so it might be an issue with your `Vitamin_D_MRS`. Can you edit your question to add a minimal, reproducible example? [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/13968222)